# Testing form data and returning a single error message (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, forms

I have to create a form and verify data has been entered into it (not that it is necessarily accurate data) prior to submitting the form. I've been able to do this with separate messages for each field, but I need to be able do it so that all the missing fields display in a single error message (IE "You are missing lastname and address and..."). Can someone please help me. Thanks in advance for any comments.

```
<FORM onSubmit='return checkForm()' NAME='customerform'>
<TABLE WIDTH=100% BORDER=1>
<TR><TD>First Name: <INPUT TYPE='TEXT' NAME='firstname'></TD>
<TD ALIGN=RIGHT> Last Name: <INPUT TYPE='TEXT' NAME='lastname'></TD></TR>
<TR><TD COLSPAN=2>Address: <INPUT TYPE='TEXT' NAME='address' size =50></TD></TR>
<TR><TD>City: <INPUT TYPE='TEXT' NAME='city'></TD>
<TD ALIGN=RIGHT>State: <INPUT TYPE='TEXT' NAME='state' size=3> Zip: <INPUT TYPE='TEXT' NAME='zip' size=6></TD>
<TR><TD COLSPAN=2>Email Address: <INPUT TYPE='TEXT' NAME='emailaddr' size=50></TD></TR>
<TR><TD><INPUT TYPE='submit' value='Submit'></TD>
<TD ALIGN=RIGHT><INPUT TYPE='reset'></TD></TR>
</TABLE></FORM>




function checkForm()
{

var data = document.customerform.firstname.value
  if (data.length <= 0) {
     alert("Please enter your first name, it is required for us to process your order.")
     return false
  }

data = document.customerform.lastname.value
  if (data.length <= 0) {
     alert("Please enter your last name, it is required for us to process your order.")
     return false
  }

data = document.customerform.address.value
  if (data.length <= 0) {
     alert("Please enter your address, it is required for us to process your order.")
     return false
  }

data = document.customerform.city.value
  if (data.length <= 0) {
     alert("Please enter your city name, it is required for us to process your order.")
     return false
  }

data = document.customerform.state.value
  if (data.length <= 0) {
     alert("Please enter your state name, it is required for us to process your order.")
     return false
  }

data = document.customerform.zip.value
  if (data.length <= 0) {
     alert("Please enter your zip code, it is required for us to process your order.")
     return false
  }

data = document.customerform.emailaddr.value
  if (data.length <= 0) {
     alert("Please enter your email, it is required for us to process your order.")
     return false
  }

}
```

Comment: I'd start by using valid HTML that conforms to standards and best practices from this decade. Seriously, this code looks like the output from Microsoft FrontPage 98.  Don't use tables for layout, don't use HTML attributes for styling (use CSS for styling), don't use inline event handlers (`onsubmit`). Instead, put all your JavaScript in separate JavaScript containers and re-format your code for readability.

Answer (score 1):

Your code has `return false` after each check, so if one fails, you never move on to the rest of the checks. You need to check all items and keep a record of the ones (if any) that fail validation and then write a single message about all of them.

Now, as I mentioned in my comment above, your code is reminiscent of code from 2000 and needs a lot of updates to follow modern standards and best-practices.

See comments in the code for details:

```js
// Get references to each element you'll want to work with:
var frm = document.querySelector("form");

// Set up event handlers the modern way and not via inline HTML event attributes
frm.addEventListener("submit", checkForm);

function checkForm(evt){
  var items = [];   // Array to hold data-id's of invalid elements
  
  // Loop through the form elements
  for(var i = 0; i < frm.elements.length; i++){
    // Check the element for no value
    if(frm.elements[i].value === ""){
      // If it has no value, put its custom data-id attribute value into the array
      items.push(frm.elements[i].dataset.id);
    }
  }
  
  // Check for errors and display message:
  if(items.length > 0){
    // Cancel the form's submission
    evt.preventDefault();
    // Turn all array items into a string, separated with commas and spaces
    // but remove the last comma and space.
    alert("You must provide entries for:\n" + items.join(", ").slice(0, -2));
  }
}
```

```css
/* Use CSS for styling, not HTML*/
#address, #emailAddr { width:25em; }
#state { width:3em; }
#zip   { width:6em; }

label.left { 
  display:inline-block;
  width:100px; 
}

/* Just for fun: */
.row {
  margin-bottom:.5em;
}

input[type=text] {
  box-shadow:0 0 1px green;
}

input[type=text]:focus {
  box-shadow:0 0 1px blue;
}
```

```html
<!-- While HTML 5 can be written in any case you like, most would agree that
     lower-case is easier to read. Next, don't use tables for layout, that's
     the job of CSS. Also, use the <label> element for better accessibility.
     But, most importantly here, if we use data-* attributes on the form
     elements, we can store a custom string that can be used later. In our
     case, in the error messages.  Take note of how clean the HTML is now
     that the styling and JavaScript have been removed from it. -->
<form name='customerform' action='#' method=''>
  <div class="row">
    <label for="firstName" class="left">First Name: </label>
    <input type='text' name='firstName' id="firstName" data-id="First Name">
    <label for="lastName">Last Name: </label>
    <input type='text' name='lastName' data-id="Last Name">
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <label for="address" class="left">Address: </label>
    <input type='text' name='address' id="address" data-id="Street Address">
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <label for="city" class="left">City: </label>
    <input type='text' name='city' id="city" data-id="City">
    <label for="state">State: </label>
    <input type='text' name='state' id="state" data-id="State">
    <label for="zip">Zip: </label>
    <input type='text' name='zip' id="zip" data-id="Zip Code">
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <label for="emailAddr" class="left">Email Address: </label>
    <input type='text' name='emailAddr' id="emailAddr" data-id="Email Address">
  </div>  
  <div class="row">
    <input type='submit' value='Submit'>
    <input type='reset'>
  </div>
</form>
```